# I want find the value of 'e' with Monte Carlo Simulation in Python, I am getting NameError

Tags: python-3.x

#Finding the value of 'e' with MonteCarlo Simulation
import random

class FindE:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.s = 0
    self.N = 1000000
    

def random_points(self):
    for i in range(1,100000):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        self.s += x
        if self.s > 1.0:
            return i


def exceed_dict(self, N):
    d = dict()
    for _ in range(N):
        count = random_points()

        if count not in d:
            d[count] = 0
        d[count] += 1

    return d


def calculating_e(self):
    d = exceed_dict(N)
    print(sum([k*v for k, v in d.items()]) / N)
```

e = FindE()
print(e.calculating_e())

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to call variable and methods inside a python class.
Don't forget to use **self.** before call it.
it should be like this :

```
import random

class FindE:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 0
        self.N = 1000000
    

    def random_points(self):
        for i in range(1,100000):
            x = random.uniform(0, 1)
            self.s += x
            if self.s > 1.0:
                return i


    def exceed_dict(self, N):
        d = dict()
        for _ in range(N):
            count = self.random_points()

            if count not in d:
                d[count] = 0
            d[count] += 1

        return d


    def calculating_e(self):
        d = self.exceed_dict(self.N)
        print(sum([k*v for k, v in d.items()]) / self.N)
e = FindE()
print(e.calculating_e())
```

Comment: Exact! Thank you very much!